# Solving functional equation using inverses

Tags: functional-equations

I am trying to solve $$f(xy)=f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+f\left(\frac{1}{y}\right), \text{with }f(0)=0$$

---

I started by getting $f(1)=2f(1)$ so $f(1)=0$, and then I had $f(x)=f(\frac{1}{x})$. But I do not know how to proceed. How do I solve this?

Comment: Logarithms might be helpful

Comment: One obvious solution is $f(x)=0$.

Comment: another is $x=\frac{1}{x} \Rightarrow x=1 \cup x=-1$

Comment: @tp1, $x=1$ does not define a function.

Comment: @goncalo: sure, but any f will do.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For $x\neq 0$, let $y=\frac{1}{x}$, then we have
$$f(1)=f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+f(x) \qquad (\text{where } x \neq 0).$$
Now, we take $y=1$, to obtain
$$f(x)=f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+f(1).$$
These equations imply that
$$f(x)=0 \qquad (\forall x \neq 0).$$
So $f(x)=0$ is the only function.